# Phone call event tracking code not working

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, analytics-events

I've set up the following event in Google Analytics

- Category Equal To Phone Call Tracking
- Action Equal To Click to Call
- Label Equal To 0123 4567
- Value Greater Than (left blank, no data
  entered)

The website is built on Wordpress. The phone number is in a text box on the web page, so I have written and inserted the following code to the html on the backend of the page.

This the html:

```
<a class="tel-home" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Phone Call Tracking', 'Click to Call', '0123 456 789', 0);" href="tel:+611234567891">0123 456 789</a>
```

Image below of where the phone number appears on the webpage[image]

When I click verify goal, I get 0% conversions. I'm sure someone has clicked to call from the webpage at some point, the business definitely get phone calls from the website.

I don't know if I've the code wrong technically, if I'm tracking the wrong kind of action on the page, or if something else is wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Goal verification is not always accurate, it's based on the past 7 days of data and depending on the sample size of data, it may be too small.

Are you seeing the events tracked in the Behaviour > Events > Overview report? 
 
How long ago did you configure the goal, they aren't retroactive in the reports, so will only track going forwards from the time of being correctly configured.

If you aren't seeing the event fire in the Real Time Reports when you test it via clicking the link..

- Do you have any filters applied in GA that are blocking your hits from being reported?
- How is the GA tracking code added to the site?
  If you are using a plugin, some of them rename the global ga object to something similar to __gaTracker (you will need to check your source code to see). In which case it will also have to be renamed in the onclick as well
- if you are using the current global site tag gtag.js version of tracking code, then the event syntax is different

  onclick="gtag('event', 'Click to Call', {'event_category': 'Click to Call','event_label': '0123 456 789'});"

Also remember if testing goals, clear cookies and cache each time you test to end the current session so you can retest. A goal only shows as a conversion once during the same session